# Tree not maintaining iterator members on recursion

Tags: c++

I'm building a simple bounding volume hierarchy, implemented in a binary search tree structure.  Sometimes a tree node ends up with multiple objects attached to it (if their centroids are in the same place, for instance).  So, I have to have each node maintain a collection of objects instead of a single pointer.

I tried to do this by having each tree node contain a specific slice of the object collection, by way of iterators.  Distributing them when generating the tree seems to work correctly, but the iterators get corrupted somehow when retrieving a leaf.

A much simplified version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "util.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Point {
public:
    Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    double x;
    double y;
};

Point elementWiseMin(Point a, Point b) {
    return Point(min(a.x, b.x), min(a.y, b.y));
}

Point elementWiseMax(Point a, Point b) {
    return Point(max(a.x, b.x), max(a.y, b.y));
}

class BoundingBox {
public:
    BoundingBox(Point minCorner, Point maxCorner) : minCorner(minCorner), maxCorner(maxCorner) {}
    Point minCorner;
    Point maxCorner;
};

class Shape {
public:
    Shape(BoundingBox* obj, Point x) : boundingBox(obj), centroid(x) {}
    BoundingBox* boundingBox;
    Point centroid;
};

typedef vector<Shape*> ShapeContainer;

class Tree {
public:
    Tree(ShapeContainer::iterator begin, ShapeContainer::iterator end) :
        begin(begin), end(end), hasNodes(true) {
        cout << end - begin << "\n";
        if (end - begin < 1) hasNodes = false;
        else {
            minCorner = (*begin)->boundingBox->minCorner;
            maxCorner = (*begin)->boundingBox->maxCorner;
            for (ShapeContainer::iterator i = begin + 1; i < end; i++) {
                minCorner = elementWiseMin(minCorner, (*i)->boundingBox->minCorner);
                maxCorner = elementWiseMax(maxCorner, (*i)->boundingBox->maxCorner);
            }

            double split = minCorner.x + ((maxCorner.x - minCorner.x) / 2);
            splitAt = split;
            ShapeContainer::iterator middle = partition(begin, end,
                [split](Shape* n) {
                return n->centroid.x < split;
            });

            if (middle - begin > 0 && end - middle > 0) {
                Tree c1 = Tree(begin, middle);
                child1 = &c1;
                Tree c2 = Tree(middle, end);
                child2 = &c2;
            }
        }
    }
    ShapeContainer::iterator begin;
    ShapeContainer::iterator end;
    Point minCorner;
    Point maxCorner;
    Tree* child1 = nullptr;
    Tree* child2 = nullptr;
    bool hasNodes;
    double splitAt;

    //get the node at x
    Tree* getNode(int x) {
        cout << end - begin << "\n";
        if (x < splitAt) {
            if (child1 == nullptr) return this;
            else return child1->getNode(x);
        }
        else {
            if (child2 == nullptr) return this;
            else return child2->getNode(x);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    ShapeContainer container;
    Shape shape1 = Shape(new BoundingBox(Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1)), Point(0.5, 0.5));
    container.push_back(&shape1);
    Shape shape2 = Shape(new BoundingBox(Point(-2, 0), Point(-1, 1)), Point(-1.5, 0.5));
    container.push_back(&shape2);
    Shape shape3 = Shape(new BoundingBox(Point(2, 0), Point(3, 1)), Point(2.5, 0.5));
    container.push_back(&shape3);
    Shape shape4 = Shape(new BoundingBox(Point(4, 0), Point(5, 1)), Point(4.5, 0.5));
    container.push_back(&shape4);

    cout << "Generate tree\n";
    Tree t = Tree(container.begin(), container.end());

    cout << "Traverse tree\n";
    Tree* node = t.getNode(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Generate tree
4
2
1
1
2
1
1
Traverse tree
4
-47673
```

The output while generating is exactly what I would expect, but it looks like the iterators don't save properly to the children.

Comment: In addition to the answer given, your code has many memory leaks and attempting to copy `Shape` objects that are not safely copyable.   How do you propose to deallocate all of that memory you allocated with `new`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your `Tree` constructor, you assign the address of a local variable to a member of the `Tree` class (`child1 = &c1`).  This is bad, because a few lines later the `c1` object goes out of scope and will be destroyed.  This leaves `child1` (and `child2`) as dangling pointers, as the object they point to is no longer valid.

You'll probably want to use dynamic memory allocation (with `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`) to properly construct the tree.

Comment: Is there a quick way to change the "return this" to a unique_ptr of this, or would I have to rework this to return its children instead?

Comment: Change `child1` and `child2` to be `std::unique_ptr<Tree>` (rather than `Tree *`), and assign them with something like `child1 = std::make_unique<Tree>(begin, middle);` in place of the two lines you currently have for each child.